# How to remove + from std::string

Tags: c++, string, char

I want to create a calculator program that is a little more advanced that just the numbers and the tiny expressions. One of the first tasks I needed to accomplish was to check if the expression entered was valid and within this i wanted to make sure that the parentheses are valid. I get a **std::string** from the console and I want to strip the expression down to only the following: (, ), [, ], {, }.

```
bool in (char elem, std::vector<char> V) {
    for (char c : V) {
        if (c == elem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void valid_parentheses(std::string s) {
    // first remove the spaces
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isspace), s.end());
    std::vector<char> valid = { '(', '[', '{', ')', ']', '}' };

    for (long unsigned int c = 0; c < s.size(); c++) {
        if (!in(s[c], valid) {
            s.erase(s.begin() + c);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "New string: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

If I call it with the input: ( ( 1 + 5 ) * [ 3 + 4 ] )

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o output && ./output
( ( 1 + 5 ) * [ 3 + 4 ] )
```

I get the output

```
New string: ((+)[+])
```

which is mostly successful, but I don't know why the *+* symbol still remains.

I know that there are many other methods to accomplish this such as appending to another string if I see one of the desired characters to just get the parantheses, braces, etc., but I am still curious why the *+* symbol still remains.

Comment: What is the definition of `in`? Please make a [mre]

Comment: the issue isn't really the + is it? Wouldn't any 3+ combo of symbols cause this? I.e. even "123". Because you're not adjusting the integer index `c` that you use to iterate when you delete a symbol

Comment: @PeterT, you are right, but I am not sure what you mean by adjusting the integer index and what I should adjust it to

Comment: I don't really see much point in validating the parentheses beforehand: while it might ensure the parentheses themselves are balanced, it doesn't tell you if the parentheses are in legal positions in the full expression. Consider the expression `(1+)`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I was trying to take a simple approach where I take  these steps in parts, so: check if the parantheses are valid, and then if they are, take care of other things.

Comment: Search the internet for "shunting yard algorithm C++".  This algorithm also accounts for operator precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, you're not modifying the index `c` when you reach a character that you want to erase. This means you skip over every character following a character that is erased. A simple fix would be to decrement `c` when erasing.

```
if (!in(s[c], valid) {
    s.erase(s.begin() + c);
    c--; // here  
}
```

Of course, you should just use an algorithm, like you did to remove spaces:

```
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](auto c){
    return !in(c, valid);
}), s.end());
```